# Javascript Mouseover, Opacity Change

Tags: javascript

Before I get into this, I'm sure that there is an answer to my question. I am new to coding, so I don't understand how to plug in the information to make it work on my site. I am trying to get a portfolio like this site: http://gomedia.com/our-work/. Here is my site so you can see the code: http://www.mattsusla.graphics. I have tried for an hour with no success. Please Help!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will allow us to better assist you.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to do this with native css. Simply call the element's hover state with `:hover`

```css
button { background: blue; }
button:hover { opacity: 0.5; }
```

```html
<button>Change Opactiy on Hover</button>
```

Let's look at the code you'd need in JavaScript

```
var button = document.getElementById("my-button");

button.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    button.style.opacity = 0.5;
});

button.addEventListener("mouesout", function() {
    button.style.opacity = 1.0;
});
```

Comment: This is correct however, it does not answer the question, its a XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I'm attempting to solve this problem with the information I have. If I get new information on the problem, I can modify this. Look at the title. I think it answers it, right?

Comment: Giving the examples of the links provided, OP is not looking for the opacity to change, rather have an overlay on hover with a dark color that has opacity. And is why I think this is a XY problem.

Comment: I see, think it should have been clearer in the question title. You can understand why some users might not understand the question title, and think it's about opacity. Thanks for pointing that out though

Comment: It's why it is just a comment and why I didn't down vote, it is an unclear question.

Comment: Between our two answers, we do have it covered for either way ;)

Comment: Thanks guys! I was looking for an overlay with a darker color. So, the question has been answered. I'm just trying to figure out how to apply the technique that @AdamBuchananSmith provided to multiple images and keep the grid.

Comment: @MattSusla if you provide a code snippet of your site, I will update my answer to better fit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need javascript for this.
Its simple done with css:

```
img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

if you want it to be more smooth, you can add a transition. this is done with css, too. only use javascript if you really need it!

```
img {
    opacity: 1;
}
img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are looking for the same functionality that is in the first site? If that is correct this will do it for you. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8sphkqkn/1/

html

```
<div id="box">

  <div id="overlay">
    <span id="text">Boss Dog Brewing Co.</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

css

```
#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
  background: url(http://s3.gomedia.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/GO_BossDogBrewery-1-e1430266175600-300x300.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 0 66px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

#box:hover #overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

#text {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  font-size: 16px;
}
```